# Inline struct usage

Tags: c++, qt, compound-literals

Considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777360/how-to-assign-a-c-struct-inline) discussion. I have the following code

```
list << (Database::ParameterX){"id_raw_tb", 100000};
```

Where,

```
QList<Database::ParameterX> list;
```

and

```
struct ParameterX {
    QString name;
    double max;
};
```

But Qt Creator 3.3.0 suggest me it's not good enought, underlining in red. However there are no error messages, program compiles and run as expected.

Why would Qt Creator underline it?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is that you are assigning an integer literal instead of a double?

Comment: If you hover with the mouse cursor above the line, do you get a tooltip saying what's wrong?

Comment: `list << (Database::ParameterX){"id_tb_raw_in", 100000.5};` remains red underlined. Hovering the mouse above shows the tip: expect token `';' got '{'`;

Comment: Then that simply means that the parser the editor is using isn't updated to handle C++11 constructs. Should hopefully be fixed in future versions, if it's not a toggle in some settings?

Answer (score 1):

The expression is valid in C99 and C++11, but not in C++98. Maybe the squiggly line checker is set to C++98, while the main compiler uses C++11.

Comment: Which would be options to get rid of the red underline?

Comment: Given the use of Qt and overloaded `<<`, is the mention of C99 relevant at all?

Comment: are you sure that this is valid C++11? it looks like a C99 compound literal, and i've never heard that this feature is available in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

The expression looks like a "compound literal" from C99, which won't work in C++.

You could change it to:

```
Database::ParameterX param = {"id_raw_tb", 100000};
list << param;
```

Or if you want to use it inline, you could define a constructor for your struct, so that you can write:

```
list << Database::ParameterX("id_raw_tb", 100000);
```

**Edit:**

With C++11, this should also work (with "uniform initialization" syntax):

```
list.append({"id_raw_tb", 100000});
```

**Edit 2:**

As for why it compiles: I tried it with GCC 4.8, and it really does compile, but when you turn on "-pedantic", it will tell you:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals
```

So this is a GCC-specific feature, and could fail to compile with other compilers. And QtCreator is most likely implemented to support standard-compliant code.